# twitter api - geo empty made with web-interface

Tags: api, twitter, location, geo

When I post a Tweet with location data on the Twitter website, the `geo` tag is empty when I call the search API. It only has the location when I Tweet from a smartphone app.

Why? Is it really like this?

Answer (score 0):

`geo` is deprecated (for about 2 years now) - use `place` instead. You should be able to find everything you need in there.